# Software and updates stuck on "Applying changes" after I select the drivers, tried doing it from terminal still doesen't use them. Plus TOR

Tags: 16.04, drivers, tor

So today I installed TOR from terminal as usual, but it simply won't show up...anywhere. Not even the Tor folder, which usually contains both the launcher and the files needed...but some days ago, it was working just fine. I Dunno why.

Then I tried to install proprietary drivers (Nvidia and Intel for the CPU) only to get it stuck on "Applying changes" for quite a while...tried googlin' the problem, tried installing them from Terminal but..still ubuntu doesen't use them, and it gets stuck on "Applying changes"...any idea?

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site. It works better if you ask one question. Otherwise you would need a expert or advanced user in all which is unlikely. I suggest you ask two separate questions because the issues are totally unrelated. Re: TOR the preferred way is simply download and run the TOR Bundle. Re: Proprietary drivers we  need (a lot) more information like hardware specs. Consider posting a new question with all that.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to run the Tor browser bundle, for the current 64 bit Linux download :

```
wget -c https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/6.5/tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz
unxz tor-browser-linux64-6.5_en-US.tar.xz
cd tor-browser_en-US/
./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Can you try this and report back ?